# Determine Direction of Normal vector of Convex Polyhedron in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, polygons

How can I determine direction(point inside or outside) of normal vector drawn on one side of the polyhedron?

Known informations;

- coordinates of all corners in 3d as x,y,z
- which face of the normal vector is drawn on

For example for this points
A (6,0,2)
B (6,0,0)
C (6,1,0)
D (6,1,2)
E (0,0,0)
F (0,1,0)
G (0,1,2)
H (0,0,2)
and normal vector which is drawn on ABCD face.

I need to prove which direction the normal vector is drawn to.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0SIC.jpg)

Comment: Take any three vertices of the polygon, P, Q, and R.  The vectors P- Q and R- Q are in the plane of the polygon.  Therefore the cross product, $(P- Q)\times (R- Q)$, is normal to the plane of the polygon.

Comment: Can we say that this normal vector point to outside of polygon or inside of polygon?(please look at the image that I attached the question) or is it possible to determine that? @user247327

Comment: @user247327: make that an answer. I thought of that also, but you beat me to it.

Comment: A "polygon" is a two-dimensional figure formed by a simple closed curve consisting of line segments. A three-dimensional figure created by intersecting planes is called a "polyhedron".

Comment: I have changed it to "polyhedron". Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already given a normal to a face of the polyhedron, you don't need to find another normal as user247327 describes. They were probably confused by your misuse of the term "polygon", like I was until I saw your picture.

Since your polyhedron is convex, for any face, all the vertices not on that face will lie on the inward side. So if $V$ lies on the face in question, and $W$ does not lie on the face, then $W - V$ will point in the general direction of the interior (though not necessarily normal to the face).

Therefore if $\vec n$ is the normal you are testing, just take the dot product:

- If $\vec n \cdot (W - V) > 0$, then $\vec n$ and $(W - V)$ are both pointing to the same side of the face, towards the inside of the polyhedron.
- If $\vec n \cdot (W - V) < 0$, then $\vec n$ and $(W - V)$ are pointing to opposite sides of the face. So $\vec n$ is pointing outward.

If your polyhedron is not convex, then greater care is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I'm so sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean by W and V. :(

Is the answer in this link basically the same as the logic of your answer? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152623/determine-the-order-of-a-3d-polygon)

Comment: $V$ is one of the vertexes on the face whose normal you are testing (any of them will do). $W$ is any vertex that is not on that face (any such vertex will do as well). In your example picture, $V$ could be any of $A, B, C, D$, while $W$ could be any of $E, F,G, H$.

Comment: I have tried with few sampling, your solution works. Thank you so much.